# Can I template a Func in C#?

Tags: c#

I am looking for how to declare a field which is a function templated by a type T.

I wish I could declare a field :

```
private Func<T> doSomething<T> where T:class;
```

where T would be a type that I declare at the moment I instanciate doSomething.
Currently I'm obliged to set it as a template of the class :

```
public class A<T>
    {
        private Func<T> doSomething;


        public A(Func<T> doSomething)
        {
            this.doSomething = doSomething;
        }

        public T Try()
        {
            return doSomething();
        }
    }
```

So If i want to call Try, I have to do so :

```
var b = new A<B>(f).Try()
```

So the information B is carried by the class A.
Is there a way to declare the Func so that I can do :

```
var b = new A(f).Try<B>()
```

??

If this is not clear, I can also paste the real code.

Comment: What would happen if you write `new A(f).Try<C>()`, passing in the same instance of `f`? Since `f` returns a `B`, what would this do?

Comment: Do you mean `public void Try<T2>(Func<T2> doSomething)`? Each method can have its own set of generic parameters, and this doesn't mean that the parent class needs to be generic at all. It would be better if you pasted the actual code, and describe what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: a field has a single type, you can´t just change it at runtime. However it seems the delegate shouldn´t be a field in the first place but just an argument of your function.

Comment: Before you go to Func, is there a way to create an instance of the generic class without specifying a generic parameter? `new A<B>(f)` is the only way. Otherwise, you have to use some factory method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can´t change a fields type. In this case this means you can´t declare the field as `Func<MyType>` and use it as if it were a `Func<AnotherType>`.

It seems however, that your field shouldn´t be a field in the first place, but just an argument of your method. So the **method itself** is generic, not the **entire class**:

```
public class A
{
    public T Try<T>(Func<T> doSomething())
    {
        return doSomething();
    }
}
```

If on the other hand all your members share the same `Func<T>`, you should of course have a single field for that. In that case using `new A<MyType>.Try()` is eactly what you need, as the generic argument belongs to the **class**, not the **method**.